# Controlar excepción "Cannot read 'property' of undefined" sin interrumpir la ejecución del programa

Tags: javascript, vanilla

me preguntaba si es posible controlar una excepción como la siguiente, sin necesidad de interrumpir la ejecución del programa, en lugar de eso, retornar un falso por ejemplo.

```js
var obj = {

    property: "something"

}

doSomething(obj);

function doSomething( obj ){
    
    var other = obj.property2.property || false ;  //Need to return false
    console.log( obj.property2 ); //Undefined
    console.log( other ); //Cannot read property of undefined
    console.log('This line is not reachable');
}

//Posible solución
function doSomething2( obj ){
    
    var other;
    if( obj.property2 ) other = obj.property2.property || false ;
    else other = false;
   
    console.log( other ); //Cannot read property of undefined
    console.log('This line is not reachable');
}
```

Como pueden ver, anexo una posible solución, pero debido a que me encuentro trabajando con integraciones, a veces tengo que hacer mucho dot walking e implementando esa posible solución tendría algunos if anidados y es algo que quiero evitar, por eso pregunto si hay alguna mejor forma de hacer esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder controlar una excepción, es necesario capturarla en un bloque [try ... catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

```
try {
    // Código que podría generar una excepción
} catch(e) {
    // Código para manejar la excepción
    // Podría ser salir de la función o asignar un valor predeterminado a una variable
}
```

Es recomendable declarar las variables usando `let` en lugar de `var`, para que solo estén disponibles en el bloque donde se definieron.

```js
let obj = {
    property: "something"
}
let obj2 = {
    property2: {
        property: 'Something'
    }
}

// El primero falla
doSomething(obj);
// El segundo funciona
doSomething(obj2);

function doSomething(obj){
    // Definir variable en el contexto de la función
    let other;
    // Si puede haber excepciones, es necesario capturarlas
    try {
        other = obj.property2.property;
    } catch(e) {
        // Capturar excepción
        console.log('Propiedad no definida en el objeto');
        // Salir de la función
        return false;
    }
    // other tiene un valor correcto
    console.log('La propiedad si está definida: ' + other);
}
```

Comment: Ya veo, parece que es la solución correcta... Juraria que ya había intentado usar el try-catch y me detuvo la ejecución del programa por eso no lo considere.... Estoy trabajando con una plataforma llamada ServiceNow por eso el motivo del uso de var en vez de let o consts. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Podes comprobar con un ternario y evitar el resto

```
function doSomething( obj ){
    
    var other = obj.property2 ? obj.property2.property : false ; 
    console.log( obj.property2 ); //Undefined
    console.log( other ); //Cannot read property of undefined
    console.log('This line is not reachable');
}
```